# ROW Prior to the MAX row, not the MIN

Tags: mysql

I have the below query to find the row prior to MAX row. i feel like i am missing something, can   somebody please help with it. I ammlooking forward to get the b.usercode_1 as row prior to   a.usercode_1 not the min or any other random row but the ROW prior to the MAX. 
Please suggest.

```
Select distinct 

c.ssn    
, c.controlled_group_Status CG_status        

, c.last_name || ' , '|| c.first_name  FULL_NAME         

, a.usercode_1 Current_REG         

, a.eff_date effective_since1      

, b.usercode_1 PRIOR_REG      

, b.eff_date effective_since2   

, d.term_eff_date   

from  employee_eff_date c   
, emp_cg_data a   
, emp_cg_data b    
, emp_ben_elects d    

where c.control_id = 'XYZ'   
and c.controlled_group_Status <> 'D'   
and c.eff_date = (select max( c1.eff_date)       
    from emp_cg_data c1           
    where c.control_id = c1.control_id         
    and c.ssn = c1.ssn)         

and a.control_id = c.control_id         
and a.ssn = c.ssn       
and a.eff_date = (select max(a1.eff_date )        
    from emp_cg_data a1  
    where a.control_id = a1.control_id       
    and a.ssn = a1.ssn)       
and a.usercode_1 = 'REG26'       

and b.control_id = c.control_id   
and b.ssn = c.ssn   
and b.eff_date = (select max( b1.eff_date)    
    from emp_cg_data b1   
    where b.control_id = b1.control_id    
    and b.ssn = b1.ssn    
    and b1.eff_date < a.eff_date)    
and b.usercode_1 like 'REG%'   

and d.control_id = c.control_id    
and d.ssn = c.ssn    
and d.life_event_date = (select max( d1.life_event_date)   
    from emp_ben_elects d1    
    where d.control_id = d1.control_id    
    and d.ssn = d1.ssn)    
and d.le_seq_no= (select max( d1.le_seq_no)    
    from emp_ben_elects d1     
    where d.control_id = d1.control_id    
    and d.ssn = d1.ssn      
    and d.life_event_date = d1.life_event_date)     
and d.term_eff_date is null      
;
```

Comment: **1** change your where to not filter a join... aka join the tables and then use the where to filter. can't read it like it is... **2** provide proper data and or a SQLFIDDLE... **3** provide a desired outcome.

Comment: What do you mean by **prior row**?  The row with the closest value to the row with the max on that column?  Using `ROW_NUMBER()` is probably how I'd approach this.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** this is not a complete answer... its a helpful suggestion of what you should start with.

you are doing a Cartesian Product of the four tables, filtered by a WHERE... so something like this

Implicit Join -- generally not a good practice as it can be very difficult to keep the where filters apart from the join conditions.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA a, TableB b
WHERE b.id = a.id
```

another way to write a JOIN (the more generally accepted way)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON b.id = a.id
```

Use the ON clause to join two tables together.

You should change your joins to this format so that others can read your query and understand it better.

---

**suggestion to solve your problem**

a fairly simple way to get the second to last row is to use a row counter.

so something like

```
SELECT *, @row_count := @row_count + 1
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b on b.id = a.id AND -- any other conditions for the join.
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_count := 0) t
```

then from here you can get the MAX row, whether thats the ID or something else. and then get the `@row_num -1`. aka the previous row.